# PHP Configuration - Memory

Tags: php, configuration

In my php.ini file I have

```
memory=40M
```

What does this do (it solves some problems that I have been having).  Note that this is NOT:

```
memory_limit=128M
```

I know memory limit sets the maximum amount of memory a PHP script can use, but what does `memory` do?

### EDIT

I recognize this is not a standard directive, but it is fixing my problem.  Without it my pages randomly produce 500 errors, but then I put this line in and they go away.

This is where I got the fix from:

http://www.archtopia.com/2010/01/30/wordpress-internal-server-error-500-with-1and1-webhosting/

Comment: The unit for "Megabyte" at `memory_limit` is `M` and not `MB`. Maybe thats the reason why it not worked.

Comment: `memory=` is bogus .. php does not recognized that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memory` is not a valid php.ini directive. It may be solving your problem because it is not recognized, in turn resorting to a default value that does in fact work. Also note that "megabyte" should be `M` not `MB`.

The proper way to set the value is:

```
memory_limit=40m
```

Comment: I don't understand then, if I don't have that line, I get random 500 errors on my pages.  Then when I put that line back in, all the problems go away...

Comment: When you take away `memory` and add `memory_limit` you get errors? What are the errors?

Comment: Regarding your edit, the article mentioned is mistaken. To provide PHP with more memory, the `memory_limit` must be upped. What happens when you replace `memory` with `memory_limit`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the memory directive on http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php. Are you sure it's correct and not a typo?